# How to find documents by startsWith() in Futon

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am working with `CouchDB` and I have to find documents whose name start with "5463"
The document structure I have is :

> {_id: "018bdd61897af56d0b3c421d4dfb1a92", _rev:
>   "1-b37c710c91450b93510f547194631aa0", type: "active_matter", id: 177,
>   name: "3009/TR02", ismaster: true}

So in `Futon` I am trying something like :

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.ismaster == true &&  (doc.name).startsWith("5463")){  
        emit([doc.type], doc);
    }
}
```

but not results are getted.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like CouchDB doesn't support the `startsWith` method. Instead use `indexOf`, with a little conditional you can use it the same way.

Using your Example:

```
function(doc){
  if(doc.ismaster && (doc.name.indexOf('5463') == 0)){
    emit([doc.type], doc);
  }
}
```

That will work the same way as `startsWith`.

Comment: yep, that's due to CouchDB still relying on an old SpiderMonkey version that doesn't support ES6 https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/946